# Error on VoltDB: HTTP service unable to bind to port 8080. Exiting

Tags: apache, voltdb

I use a mac. And I installed VoltDB and compile CREATE sentence but, the error "HTTP service unable to bind to port 8080. Exiting." has occurred.
My installed flow is below:

```
brew install voltdb

vim users.sql
->  CREATE TABLE users (
       user_id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
       user_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
       created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    );

voltdb compile -o users.jar users.sql   

voltdb create users.jar
```

then the above error has occurred.

```
Initializing VoltDB...

 _    __      ____  ____  ____ 
| |  / /___  / / /_/ __ \/ __ )
| | / / __ \/ / __/ / / / __  |
| |/ / /_/ / / /_/ /_/ / /_/ / 
|___/\____/_/\__/_____/_____/

--------------------------------

Build: 6.9 This is not from a known repository Community Edition
Connecting to VoltDB cluster as the leader...
Host id of this node is: 0
FATAL: HTTP service unable to bind to port 8080. Exiting.
java.lang.Exception: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

I checked my localhost:8080 and the following page was shown.(My php version is very old, so please don't care.)
[image]

I also checked port status of use, then the result is below:

```
sudo lsof -P -i:8080
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   *****   root    **  IPv6 *****************      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
httpd   ***** daemon    **  IPv6 *****************      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
httpd   ***** daemon    **  IPv6 *****************      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
httpd   ***** daemon    **  IPv6 *****************      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

Then I killed all above processes, and the result of "sudo lsof -P -i:8080" became empty. Again I tried to execute "voltdb create users.jar", but same error has occurred and the result of port status wasn't empty(same as above status).
How can I use a voltdb on my mac?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue you're hitting seems to be that you have EnterpriseDB listening on port 8080, so VoltDB is unable to bind to the port. The ports that VoltDB uses are listed here, along with instructions on how to override them: https://docs.voltdb.com/AdminGuide/HostConfigPortOpts.php

VoltDB does not support homebrew install. It's nice to see things like this cropping up, though. However, if you continue to run into issues, I would recommend that you either download VoltDB from [voltdb.com](https://www.voltdb.com/try-voltdb/), or follow the [Github wiki instructions](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/wiki/Building-VoltDB) for building VoltDB from source code.

Lastly, it seems you are using outdated commands. The "voltdb compile" command was deprecated when v5.0 was released, in favor of interactive DDL. The "voltdb create" command and related "join", "recover", and "add" commands were deprecated in v6.8. and replaced with a much [simpler set of commands](https://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/clivoltdb.php) "voltdb init" and "voltdb start". I recommend that you go through the [Welcome to VoltDB tutorial](https://docs.voltdb.com/tutorial/) which demonstrates the basics using all the latest commands.

Disclaimer: I work for VoltDB.